# Understand Vue and Return and Async Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, es6-promise

I am new to Javascript and Vue and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around return, async and await work together. I come from a Python background and JS syntax is quite different

So... some background to the problem....I'm building a Vue blog and creating multiple Vuex stores using module mode. I am also creating a function to retrieve data from Prismic.

**./store/blog.js**

```
import {MyFunctions} from "../plugins/myfunctions.js";

export const actions = {
    async retrievePosts() {
        console.log("HELLO")
        return MyFunctions.MyFunction("blog_post");
    }
}
```

**./plugins/myfunctions.js**

```
import Prismic from "prismic-javascript";
import PrismicDom from "prismic-dom" //importing the Dom
import PrismicConfig from "../prismic.config.js";

export const MyFunctions = {
    MyFunction: async function (doctype) {
        console.log("Before")
        const api = await Prismic.getApi(PrismicConfig.apiEndpoint)
        let blog_post = {}
        const results = await api.query(
            Prismic.Predicates.at("document.type", doctype),
            { lang: "en-us" } //This is a Prismic query option
        )
        console.log("After")
        result = results.results

        return result;
    }
};
```

Heres my question:

1. In blog.js, if I remove the word "return" in front of MyFunctions.MyFunction("blog_post") , the await in myfunctions.js do not get activated. Why?
   I say this because without the return, "Before" is console logged but "After" is not and nothing is returned.

A further question for my enlightenment:

1. Where does return MyFunctions.MyFunction("blog_post") return to? So the data is returned to retrievePosts() but it is part of a {} which is a javascript object I believe? So does it become like a property inside {}?

Comment: question 1. - not sure why, it just means you'd return undefined, question 1. the value is returned to whatever calls `retrievePosts` - which isn't shown in the code you've provided

Comment: FYI - There's no point in your `retrievePosts` action being an `async` function since it doesn't use `await`. You could just make it a normal function

Comment: Thanks Phil, appreciate the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans 1:You are actually returning a function to the caller of retrievePosts() in async mode. By removing return, function will be executed but it don't make any effect to the caller of retrievePosts() function.

Ans 2:The MyFunctions.MyFunction("blog_post") is returned to the caller of retrievePosts() function.

Comment: You can read this article: https://medium.com/better-programming/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. You can upvote my answer as well 